# Loopback 4 - Eager Load Detail Table

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm new to Loopback 4 and am having an issue mapping our current database structure to the ORM.  We currently use detail tables a lot to store secondary object data, such as addresses.  For example we might have two tables related as so:

```
"Offices" table
id: string;
officeName: string;              "Addresses" table
addressId: string; ============> id: string;
                                 line1: string;
                                 line2: string;
                                 city: string;
                                 state: string;
                                 zip: number;
```

Then we use a DTO to map the data as follows:

```
"Office" DTO
id: string;
officeName: string;
addressLine1: string;
addressLine2: string;
addressCity: string;
addressState: string;
addressZip: number;
```

However i'm having trouble figuring out how to eager load the address detail table so when I create the DTO using the model it will map correctly.  I can see how to do this manually, but I'm looking for a solution that eager loads the child "address" record with the parent "office" record.

For reference I've set up my models and repositories as documented here:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/BelongsTo-relation.html

The  office belongs to the address, since the address primary key is stored in the office record.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Turns out this is not possible/hasn't been implemented yet.  Our next solution will unfortunately not include Loopback due to this.

Source: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1352